# Can I make EC2 instance visible to all users in an organisation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-access-policy

I have an organization and I want one user to create the EC2 and all other to be able to access it. Is that possible?

Comment: Why mention the "organization"? Are you wanting to let people from other organizations access it? Through another VPC? And what does "access" mean? SSH? via the console?

Comment: How will the users access the EC2 instance? Using Remote Desktop (if Windows), SSH, port 80/443 from a web browser, make service API call against the EC2 instance, something else?

Comment: Access through the aws . When they log in with their account  to be able to see it alongside their ec2 instances(in the UI).

Comment: All EC2 instances for a given AWS account are visible to all IAM users in the AWS console for that account (unless a user has limited permissions). What do you want the other users to be able to do with the EC2 instances?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:
Depending on how you grouped your "organization", implementation methods vary.

For example, if you defined it outside AWS, you can share the SSH key inside a shared, controlled space for your organization (like a Github repo). This isn't recommended for obvious security reasons. If you like the SSH route, it may be worth looking into setting up `AWS Secrets Manager` to create "[rotating keys](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-secrets-manager-securely-store-rotate-ssh-key-pairs/)" such that previously shared keys won't grant malicious users access.

You could also look into setting up `AWS Session Manager` which ties into your IAM roles/policies and therefore allows you to do your access management within AWS.

There are many other methods in setting up user management, but these are the ones I see most frequent.

Comment: I can give ssh access to anyone, but i want my ec2 to be visible in their account when they log in  aws through the browser and see it under ec2 instances

Comment: Having your ec2 instance show up in their console page isn't possible if you are talking about separate accounts.